# Append a file to the beginning of other files

Tags: bash

I need to query all javascript files in a folder (except 'pre.js') and prepend each file with the content of pre.js

it seems fairly easy to do for a single file:

```
cat pre.js |cat - foo.js  > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out foo.js
```

but I have multiple files in the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more general form of the other answer:

```
for i in *.js ; do if [[ "${i}" != pre.js ]] ; then cat pre.js "${i}" > $$ ; mv $$ "${i}" ; fi ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

That calls for a simple one-liner loop:

```
for f in foo.js bar.js baz.js; do cat pre.js $f > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out $f; done
```

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is the standard editor:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for f in !(pre).js; do ed -s "$f" << END
0r pre.js
w
q
END
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
find folder/ -name '*.js' \! -name 'pre.js' -exec sh -c 'cat pre.js "$1" > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out "$1"' _ {} \;
```